# Convert dump file produced by svnadmin back to folder

Tags: svn

I have a gzipped file which was produced by running svnadmin dump on a subversion repository. I can unzip the file using gzip -d, but how do I then convert the dump back into the folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `svadmin load`. You'll be loading an svn repository, not a directory structure, so you'll need to check out the loaded repository to get a working copy of the project directory structure.